# Replacing acronyms with their full forms in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have an acronym dictionary that has `keys` as an acronym and `values` as full forms.

I want to replace the acronyms found in the `text_list` with the full forms to arrive at the `ouput_list`

```
acronym_dict = {
    'QUO': 'Quotation',
    'IN': 'India',
    'SW': 'Software',
    'RE': 'Regular Expression'
}

text_list = [
    'The status QUO has changed', 'I SWEAR, This is part of IN_SW',
    'The update does not belong to the SW, version, branch',
    'This is a RE_Text'
]

output_list = [
    'The status Quotation has changed',
    'I SWEAR, This is part of India_Software',
    'The update does not belong to the Software, version, branch',
    'This is Regular Expression_Text'
]
```

I wrote a method to do that

```
import string
def remove_punctuations(text):
    punct_str = string.punctuation  # !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~
    for punctuation in punct_str:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, ' ')
    return text.strip()

def replace_single_acronym(text, acronym, fullform):
    words = text.split()
    return_words = []
    for w in words:
        if remove_punctuations(w).lower() == acronym.lower():
            return_words.append(w.replace(acronym, fullform))
        else:
            return_words.append(w)
    return " ".join(return_words)

my_op_list = []
for text in text_list:
    for acronym in acronym_dict.keys():
        text = replace_single_acronym(text, acronym, acronym_dict[acronym])
    my_op_list.append(text)
```

Ideally `output_list` and `my_op_list` should look the same. It prints the below result (failing in 2 instances)

```
['The status Quotation has changed',
 'I SWEAR, This is part of IN_SW',
 'The update does not belong to the Software, version, branch',
 'This is a RE_Text']
```

Also, the method `replace_single_acronym` is very slow on a corpus of 1000 `text_list` items.

Can someone help me in adjusting the method to do it in the right and efficient way?

Comment: why do you use a regex to remove the punctuation, but not a regex to replace the acronyms with their expansion? If you already know how to use regexes, that's very easy, and probably much faster than what you're doing!

Comment: Agreed. The main challenge I am facing is finding the right `regex` that fits all the example conditions (i.e. with space or punctuation before and after and the acronym itself should not be a part of the word). It will be great if you can help me with the regex. Note: I am not super comfortable with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for this task by delivering function as 2nd argument following way

```
import re
acronym_dict = {
    'QUO': 'Quotation',
    'IN': 'India',
    'SW': 'Software',
    'RE': 'Regular Expression'
}

text_list = [
    'The status QUO has changed', 'I SWEAR, This is part of IN_SW',
    'The update does not belong to the SW, version, branch',
    'This is a RE_Text'
]
def get_full_name(m):
    return acronym_dict.get(m.group(1),m.group(1))
def replace_acronyms(text):
    return re.sub(r'(?<![A-Z])([A-Z]+)(?![A-Z])', get_full_name, text)
output_list = [replace_acronyms(i) for i in text_list]
print(output_list)
```

output:

```
['The status Quotation has changed', 'I SWEAR, This is part of India_Software', 'The update does not belong to the Software, version, branch', 'This is a Regular Expression_Text']
```

Explanation: in pattern I used there are two zero-length assertions and one capturing group, it does find one or more uppercase ASCII letters, which are not preceded by ASCII uppercase letter (*negative lookbehind*) and not followed by ASCII uppercase letter (*negative lookahead*). `get_full_name` is function used as 2nd argument of `re.sub` thus it do accept single argument, which is match. `m.group(1)` denote content of sole capturing group I have used in pattern, it is acronym, I used `.get` function of `dict` so if given acronym is present in dict keys then use corresponding value, if it is not just use that acronym i.e. do not change anything.

Comment: Great. Thanks. This works. I will test it out with a larger sample and accept the answer in a bit.